# Toast shows before sending message

Tags: android, text, chat

I am making chat app in which users can't send empty messages. Before sending a message, the toast displays "empty field". I want to show a toast only when users try to send message when the field is empty. What to do?

```
public class  chat_app extends AppCompatActivity{

    InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
    private InterstitialAd interstitial;

    private Button btn_send_msg;
    private EditText input_msg;
    private TextView chat_conversation;

    private String user_name,room_name;
    private DatabaseReference root ;
    private String temp_key;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat_room);

        btn_send_msg = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_send);
        input_msg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.msg_input);
        chat_conversation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        user_name = getIntent().getExtras().get("user_name").toString();
        room_name = getIntent().getExtras().get("room_name").toString();
        setTitle(" Room - "+room_name);


        root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(room_name);

        btn_send_msg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                temp_key = root.push().getKey();
                root.updateChildren(map);

                DatabaseReference message_root = root.child(temp_key);
                Map<String,Object> map2 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                map2.put("name",user_name);
                map2.put("msg",input_msg.getText().toString());

                message_root.updateChildren(map2);

            }


        });

        root.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                append_chat_conversation(dataSnapshot);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                append_chat_conversation(dataSnapshot);

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }

        });

    }


    private String chat_msg,chat_user_name;

    private void append_chat_conversation(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        Iterator i = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();

        while (i.hasNext()){

            chat_msg = (String) ((DataSnapshot)i.next()).getValue();
            chat_user_name = (String) ((DataSnapshot)i.next()).getValue();

            chat_conversation.append(chat_user_name +" : "+chat_msg +" \n\n");
            input_msg.setText("");
            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(chat_msg)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Empty field ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
        }
`
```

Answer (score 1):

check your edit text value in onclik method if it is empty show toast msg

```
btn_send_msg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(input_msg.getText().toString().equals("")){

            // Toast msg here

           }else{
            Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            temp_key = root.push().getKey();
            root.updateChildren(map);

            DatabaseReference message_root = root.child(temp_key);
            Map<String,Object> map2 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            map2.put("name",user_name);
            map2.put("msg",input_msg.getText().toString());

            message_root.updateChildren(map2);
             }
        }


    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to check it before sending i am considering **btnsend** is where you sending message

```
btn_send_msg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            if(input_msg.getText().toString().trim().length>0)**///considering input is your editetxt of message to send**
            {
                Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                temp_key = root.push().getKey();
                root.updateChildren(map);

                DatabaseReference message_root = root.child(temp_key);
                Map<String,Object> map2 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                map2.put("name",user_name);
                map2.put("msg",input_msg.getText().toString());

                message_root.updateChildren(map2);
           }
           else
           {
               **///show empty toast here**
           }



            }


        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
btn_send_msg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
         String message = input_msg.getText().toString().trim(); //Throw gaps
        if(message.equals("")){

        // Toast msg here

       }else{
        Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        temp_key = root.push().getKey();
        root.updateChildren(map);

        DatabaseReference message_root = root.child(temp_key);
        Map<String,Object> map2 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map2.put("name",user_name);
        map2.put("msg",input_msg.getText().toString());

        message_root.updateChildren(map2);
         }
    }


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add checking in your `send` buttons `onClick()` method:

```
   btn_send_msg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String message = input_msg.getText().toString();

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(message)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Empty field", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                temp_key = root.push().getKey();
                root.updateChildren(map);

                DatabaseReference message_root = root.child(temp_key);
                Map<String,Object> map2 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                map2.put("name", user_name);
                map2.put("msg", message);

                message_root.updateChildren(map2);
            }
    });
```

And your `append_chat_conversation()` method as below:

```
private void append_chat_conversation(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    Iterator i = dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator();

    while (i.hasNext()){

        chat_msg = (String) ((DataSnapshot)i.next()).getValue();
        chat_user_name = (String) ((DataSnapshot)i.next()).getValue();

        chat_conversation.append(chat_user_name +" : "+chat_msg +" \n\n");

    }

 }
```